# I can't loaddata from backup.json, in django

Tags: django

I hosted a site and around 200 persons data is stored in that, I took backup of it to test in my modified site, I mean I am developing that site more, But when I loaddata then it gives errors like:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\Users\siddh\Projects\Django_Projects\XtraROMs\dump.json': Could not load app.UserProfile(pk=1): UNIQUE constraint failed: app_userprofile.user_id`

I tried many things like deleting the database and migrations and many other things on stackoverflow, github and chatgpt, But It is not loading, even I tried to use same models as my hosted site but it gives errors

These are models in my running project:

- class CustomROM(models.Model):
- class CustomMOD(models.Model):
- class UserProfile(models.Model):
  `user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True) is_authorized = models.BooleanField(default=False)`
- class Contact(models.Model):
- class Comment(models.Model):

These are models in my running project: (It is same as my running project except some extra attributes in my UserProfile model)

- class CustomROM(models.Model):
- class CustomMOD(models.Model):
- class UserProfile(models.Model):
  `user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True) is_authorized = models.BooleanField(default=False) profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/', blank=True) bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True) google_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True) local_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True) email = models.EmailField(blank=True)`
- class Contact(models.Model):
- class Comment(models.Model):

Also, I used django allauth feature in modified site but it is not related to this i guess

I already used these commands :

```
python manage.py reset_db
python manage.py flush
```

Kindly fix this issue, and give a better solution that can hel in many senarios.

Answer (score 0):

"`UNIQUE constraint failed`" means you're trying to add the same `user_id` in the database twice.

If your db is truly empty when you try to populate it, then it means the problem is in your JSON. Check your `dump.json` manually, with a text editor, for any duplicate user_id.

Comment: Yeh Thanks, this solved the issue, it is due to two superusers with same name, now I have done unique=True, I forget this thing, Thanks for review